# Extend products with custom module in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am writing a module, I know how to build a global module, but I would like to do the following:

- Have global properties (already covered)
- Have the same properties in a tab in the products interface in the admin where the user can override the global properties (still to do)

Now my question:

- How do I add an additional tab to the products interface in the prestashop admin?
- I guess I can easily call these in my module templates and check if global is overridden?

Thanks for the feedback,
Eric

*PS.  Using prestashop 1.5.8, will worry later to extend to 1.6*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an additional tab to product edit page, you can use hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra.

First, you will have to register this hook inside install() method:

```
public function install() {
   ...
   $this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra')...
   ...
}
```

after that you define this:

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params) {
...
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/admin/yourtemplatefile.tpl');
}
```

File yourtemplatefile.tpl defines the contents of your extra tab. Extra variables used in this file can be assigned inside hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra function

Here you can find additional information about creating a module:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module

And here you can find information about hooks:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5

Comment: Thanks, that what I needed. Now I can continue

Comment: doesn't work in prestashop_1.6.1.4 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740500/prestashop-1-6-hookdisplayadminproductsextra-is-not-called